# getting a list of images with specific tags via Flickr API in Python

Tags: python, flickr

I am using the flickrapi (http://stuvel.eu/flickrapi) to retrieve a list of images that are tagged with '#e-waste'.

Here is a code I tried so far but it is not working the way I want it to:

```
import flickrapi
api_key='********************************'

print flickr.photos_search(tags = "e-waste")
```

It returns this (??):

```
<Element 'rsp' at 0x1037a4110>
```

Please help, it's a simple task but I'm a total beginner with Flickr API.

Comment: You could use `flickr.photos_search(tags='e-waste', format='json')` to get a more readable output. Here: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.search you can experiment with this particular method and see what it returns

Comment: It still gave me a blank output. But managed to save this with importing xml and printing an xml tree.